# Allow Save new item and continue in SharePoint NewForm.aspx

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

**Short :** How to make a default SharePoint NewForm.aspx add an item and stay on the input page instead of returning to the list view AllItems?

**long :**
I am asked to allow SharePoint users to enter many new items to a SharePoint list without having to return to AllItems each time they save.
This requirement applies to many lists so I don't want to develop specific code for every possible content type.
I though I could write a short js file and use it whenever the the user wants to save and continue.
So far I tried to add the "Save and continue" behavior in a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP).
My first approach was to change the **Source=** parameter with no success (either cancel returned also to the new source or the source was ignored when set in preSaveAction().
Then I tried to set the form action in preSaveAction :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
var src      = JSRequest.QueryString["Source"];
var exit     = JSRequest.QueryString["exit"];
var isDialog = JSRequest.QueryString["IsDlg"];
var dlgParam = "";
if (isDialog)
    dlgParam = "&IsDlg="+isDialog;
//If exit is defined its keeping default source parameter
if (exit) {
    document.forms.aspnetForm.action= location.pathname+"?Source="+exit+dlgParam;
}
function PreSaveAction(){
    //before saving the original source is saved in exit
    exit=JSRequest.QueryString["Source"];
    src=escapeProperly(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath);
    document.forms.aspnetForm.action=location.pathname+"?Source="+src+"&exit="+exit+dlgParam;
return true;
```

The action is updated as expected but the user is still redirected to AllItems.aspx when a new item is saved.

Another attempt was to add a specific button reusing the SharePoint javascript action used in the ribbon and page buttons

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function adressePage() {
    return window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath;
}

function saveContinue() {
    document.getElementById("cmdSaveContinue").disabled=true;

    if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
    if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm("WPQ2")) {
        SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("Saving ...", false);
        window.location = adressePage();
    } else {
        WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("cmdSaveContinue", "", true, "", adressePage(), false, true));
    }
    document.getElementById("cmdSaveContinue").disabled=false;      
}
</script>
<input id="cmdSaveContinue" onclick="javascript:return saveContinue();" type="button" value="Enregistrer et continuer" style="top: -5.5em; position: relative;"/>
```

This way, form validation is processed and the item is saved.
If error messages are returned, the form stays on NewItem but the error messages are lost after the `window.location=...` is executed.
When everything works well, the item is saved and the user is on a new empty NewForm.aspx.
But SharePoint `SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm("WPQ2")` is executed asynchronously and sometimes (not always) the redirection to 
AllItems occurs after the end of my redirection.

I am stuck at this point and fear to be forced to edit each and every NewForm page in SPDesigner whenever a list is added...

Infos : SharePoint server 2013 on premise, SPDesigner possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through InfoPath, which you should be able to use if you have SP on prem and SPDesigner access. If you go to InfoPath and customize the form, you can go to Data > Submit Options > (advanced >>) > After Submit > New Form.

You can either google 'InfoPath Save and New' or go to the Microsoft site and check out [this](http://community.office365.com/en-us/b/office_365_buzz/archive/2013/05/21/infopath-save-and-new-button-grid-user-post.aspx) walkthrough. Their walkthrough suggests using two buttons, one of which opens a new form and the other which closes the form.

Comment: having to edit every NewForm with a discontinued product is going to involve a lot a work. I will lose less time explaining the users that it's not possible yet. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom NewForm.aspx and add a new button and mention {} in redirect.

```
<input type="button" class="contact-button" value="Submit and Create New Request" name="btnSaven" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={}')}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

add script editor web part to a view

```
<input type="button" value="Add items in continuity" onclick="openNewItemDialog()"/>
<script>
    function openNewItemDialog() {
        var options = {
            url: 'http://sp/sites/dev/Lists/<yourList>/NewForm.aspx',
            dialogReturnValueCallback: function(result, returnValue) {
                if(result== SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)
                { 
                    openNewItemDialog()
                }
            }
        }
     SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```